# Text mode web browser with support for Persian words

Tags: web-browser

I am looking for a text mode browser with this conditions:

1. support Persian words
2. low CPU / memory usage
3. tabbed environment
4. can switch between image and not image (like usage of `*` character in `links2`)
5. Flash/JavaScript not needed
6. enable/disable cookies (like `w3m`)
7. understand tables

`w3m` and `links2` nearly have most of them, except of `supporting Persian words) which is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm tested w3m and lynx to browse Persian web sites and it work for me.
[image]

Maybe you must configure bash or other console program to support utf-8 (Persian character) in command line.